# CompatTelRunner.exe is causing 100% CPU usage

Tags: windows-10, cpu-usage

Since my last Windows 10 Update, **CompatTelRunner.exe** is causing 100% CPU usage after Windows start. This results in not being able to use my computer for a long time. How can I fix this?

Windows OS Build is 19042.1052

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`CompatTelRunner.exe` is a component of Windows Compatibility Telemetry,
periodically sending anonymous usage and performance data to Microsoft
developers to help improve Windows.

Its default location is `C:/Windows/System32/`, which you should verify.
A good tool for this is
[Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).
If the folder is wrong, then this is actually a virus.

First verify the state of Windows by running
[sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

If this doesn't help, you can disable it by one of these methods
(reboot is required):

- Run Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`) and position to
  *Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Data Collection and Preview Builds*.
  Double-click "Allow Telemetry", select Disable, then click OK. (For Win11 see comments below)
- Run Task Scheduler (`taskschd.msc`) and position to
  *Task Scheduler Library > Microsoft > Windows > Application Experience*.
  Right-click the "Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser" task,
  and select Disable.
- Edit the registry: Run `regedit`, position to
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DataCollection`,
  right-click the right pane and select
  "New > DWORD (32-bit) Value". Name it `AllowTelemetry` and set its
  value to `0`.

Comment: `AllowTelemetry` wo space: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/desktop-analytics/group-policy-settings#windows-settings

Comment: For anyone not finding Allow Telemetry in the Group Policy Editor, apparently, it was renamed to Allow Diagnostic Data (confirmed on my Windows 11 Enterprise, 21H2, source: https://www.elevenforum.com/t/help-finding-allow-telemetry-in-local-group-policy-editor.5671/post-110213).

If what you want is to avoid the sending of telemetry, make sure you set this policy to "Enabled" and choose the option of "Diagnostic data off (not recommended)".

Comment: What if I don't want to disable it but fix it? Surely it's not normal for it to be consuming 100% CPU all day and night? Perhaps there's some kind of telemetry cache that needs to be cleared to reset it?

Answer (score -5):

Process Hacker is a good task manager. You can use Process Hacker to stop program.

> Danger! If is a important program, do not stop it. Please talk with your PC administrator.

Comment: Do you mean **PROCESS HACKER**?

Comment: Yes! But you can do not use this program. It's your choice

Comment: Soory! My bad english

Comment: Virus Total reports about `processhacker-2.39-setup.exe`: 21 security vendors flagged this file as malicious (!) MD5: 54daad58cce5003bee58b28a4f465f49

Comment: It's no virus but if you think that program is virus, do not use.

Comment: //Can you stop progress this program(not progresshacker)

Comment: @EGEDEMOfficial - Feel free to edit your answer instead of submitting commentary

Comment: Been using microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ processhacker daily  for years with no negative  issues. Helpful.  https://www.virustotal.com/ reports "No security vendors flagged this URL as malicious"  All who reported list it as clean: https://download.sysinternals.com/files/ProcessExplorer.zip